# How to differentiate samples on the x axis using ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, figure, geom-bar

I have created a geom_bar plot using ggplot which has 14 individual samples along the x axis. These samples belong to different groups and I was hoping to add an element to the figure which would indicate which samples belong to each group.

For example in this output figure, samples HH11-HH21 belong to one group, HH21-35 belong to another and the remainder belong to another group. 
[image: For example in this output figure, samples HH11-HH21 belong to one group, HH21-35 belong to another and the remainder belong to another group]

Is if possible to add a coloured bar along the top of the figure which indicates which group the samples belong to?

This is the code I used to generate this figure:

```
ggplot(full_table_top30, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Genus)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = Genus2, values = Cb64k) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  theme(legend.position = "right", text=element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  ggtitle(opt$gtitle) +
  xlab("Patient ID") + ylab("Relative activity")
```

Comment: Hi mrad, I think you might need to combine two plots.. The other plot will be a horizontal bar plot with what you need. And you combine using cowplot or grid.arrange in gridExtra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have your data, but I think what you're looking for is `facet_grid()`. If we build some data:

```
df <- tibble(class = rep(c("H1", "H2", 
                           "H3", "H4"), each = 3),
             variable = rep(c("V1","V2",
                              "V3"), 4),
             value = sample(20:50, 12),
             group = ifelse(class == "H1" | class == "H2", 
                            "Group 1", "Group 2"))
```

Then plot it:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(group), scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
```

[image]
Within `facet_grid()` you specify your group variable, and use "free_x" so that each facet only contains variables for the specific group. Finally, faceting adds space between the two plots. You can delete this by zeroing out the panel spacing.

And you can change the color of the facets with the following: 
`theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill="#ff0000", color = NA))`

#### Addendum

```
mutate(full_table_top30, group = ifelse(variable == "HH11" | variable == "HH12" | 
                                            variable == "HH15" | variable == "HH21", "PEDIS2", 
                                          ifelse(variable == "HH1" | variable == "HH18" | 
                                            variable == "HH20" | variable == "HH24" | 
                                            variable == "HH34" | variable == "HH35", 
                                            "PEDIS3", "PEDIS4")))
```

Comment: Hi Taylor, that's exactly what I was after! I'm relatively new to R so I'm having a bit of trouble interpreting your examples to my data. There are three columns in my data with the headings |Genus|variable|value|. With variable being my Sample ID (HH*) and value being read counts of my genus of interest.

In your example you mention using the group <- ifelse to group the data, which you then use as input for facet_grid. Given the sample names in the above figure, how would I use the ifelse command to separate the samples into "Group 1, Group 2, Group 3"?

Comment: @mrad you can use a nested ifelse statement based on the "variable" column and would look similar to this `mutate(group = ifelse(variable == "HH11" | variable == "HH12" | variable == "HH15", "Group 1",
                             ifelse(variable == "HH24" | variable == "H1", "Group 2", "Group 3")))` obviously you would need to add the right variable names in. as an alternative, you can also use the `case_when()` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when)

Comment: @TaylorI tried the following: 
```mutate(group = ifelse(variable == "HH11" | variable = "HH12" | variable == "HH15" | variable == "HH21", "PEDIS2", ifelse(variable == "HH1" | variable == "HH18" | variable == "HH20" | variable == "HH24" | variable == "HH34" | variable == "HH35", "PEDIS3", ifelse(variable == "HH31" | variable == "HH33" | variable == "HH4" | variable == "HH5", "PEDIS4"))))```
Which gave me this error: Error: unexpected '=' in "mutate(group = ifelse(variable == "HH11" | variable ="

Comment: @mrad you need to use "==" when within the ifelse logic. you only have one "=" with HH12

Comment: thanks for your help with this. That fixed that problem but now I get this error:
```mutate(group = ifelse(variable == "HH11" | variable == "HH12" | variable == "HH15" | variable == "HH21", "PEDIS2", ifelse(variable == "HH1" | variable == "HH18" | variable == "HH20" | variable == "HH24" | variable == "HH34" | variable == "HH35", "PEDIS3", ifelse(variable == "HH31" | variable == "HH33" | variable == "HH4" | variable == "HH5", "PEDIS4"))))
Error in is.data.frame(.data) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default```

Comment: So I added my data frame and got this error:
```mutate("full_table_top30", group = ifelse(variable == "HH11" | variable == "HH12" | variable == "HH15" | variable == "HH21", "PEDIS2", ifelse(variable == "HH1" | variable == "HH18" | variable == "HH20" | variable == "HH24" | variable == "HH34" | variable == "HH35", "PEDIS3", ifelse(variable == "HH31" | variable == "HH33" | variable == "HH4" | variable == "HH5", "PEDIS4"))))
Error in mutate("full_table_top30", group = ifelse(variable == "HH11" |  : 
  is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) is not TRUE```

Comment: But my data definitely is a data frame:
```str(full_table_top30)
'data.frame': 210 obs. of  3 variables:```

Comment: try running it again, but don't put your dataframe name in quotation. so, `mutate(full_table_top30, group = ...)`

Comment: When doing that I get this error: ```Error in ifelse(variable == "HH31" | variable == "HH33" | variable ==  : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default```

Comment: I added code in an "addendum" in the original code above. the `ifelse()` function requires that you provide an "if" and an "else" (this is the no in the error message). the way your code is styled, you provide 3 if's with no "else". what the addendum code says is that if logic group 1 is met, then it's "PEDIS2", if logic group 2 is met, then it's "PEDIS3", and if doesn't meet either logic group, then it's "PEDIS4"

Comment: Instead of so many `|`, use `%in%`: `ifelse(variable %in% c("HH11", "HH12", "HH15", "HH21"), "PEDIS2", ifelse(variable %in% c("HH1", "HH18", "HH20", "HH24", "HH34", "HH35"), "PEDIS3", "PEDIS4"))`

Comment: @Taylor that did it thank you so much! One other little thing if you can help, now the samples are grouped the bars in the middle group (PEDIS3) are thinner than those in the PEDIS 2 and PEDIS 4 groups. Do you know if it's possible to force the bars to be the same width across all groups? I assume they are thinner because there is 6 samples vs 4 for the other two groups.

Comment: @mrad regarding the bar width issues, try adding `space = "free_x"` as an argument inside `facet_grid()`.

Comment: @Gregor that did it! Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @Taylor Hi again, the code you provided worked great! I'm now trying to replicate it with a much larger dataset (9x PEDIS2, 16x PEDIS3 and 11xPEDIS4) but I am finding that when using the same code as above, none of my samples are being grouped as PEDIS4. The code correctly places my first 9 samples as PEDIS2, but then groups the remaining 27 as PEDIS3 and completely omits PEDIS4. Is there any way I can change the code so that it correctly groups the PEDIS4 samples?

Comment: @mrad Without the data or the code, it's difficult to tell exactly what's happening but it sounds like you're having issues with both PEDIS3 and PEDIS4. I recommend trying to group a subset of your code - try to group 1 or 2 samples into each group using the `%in%` function from Gregor above and see if you can get that to work. If that works, then you can continue to add to each group until you've accounted for everything